# Pushpins hides from overlapping bing map

Tags: dictionary, bing, pushpin

I have created a bing map application and in browser two overlapping Bing Map appears. One map hide another. Pushpins are getting displayed on the map which was hidden. How to overcome that, please let me know ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking through your code and seeing if you are loading Bing Maps twice to different div's or have two div's with the same ID. If so check to see if it's needed. Did you mean to have two maps? I haven't come across this question before and I suspect that  the issue you are having might be that your are finding two pushpins are overlapping and you want to know how to display the hidden one. In this case you would want to implement clustering. Take a look at this module for Bing Maps: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client%20Side%20Clustering